# PLAY - REST with JAVA - basic GET request

Tags: java, json, rest, playframework-2.0

I use play framework for my server-side with the reast api and java for the actual server-side functions.
I'm trying to make a simple GET request, to get Array of Json. But it gives me an error in the Users when I use Json.toJson. why is that ??

the User is a simple class for the user object( "user name:, password:, first name: ,last name").

```
public class Users extends Controller {
    private static ArrayList<User> Users = new ArrayList(){{
        add(new User("a","2","a","a"));
    }};
    public static Result index(){
        return ok(Json.toJson(Users)); 
    }
}
```

**edit 1 - the answer:**

my problem was that I imported the wrong java lib for the play Result . the right one is :

```
import play.mvc.Result;
```

Comment: What error exactly? Also, is both your Class and ArrayList called **Users**?

Comment: 'toJson(play.api.libs.json.Writes<java.lang.Object>)' in 'play.api.libs.json.Json$' cannot be applied to '(java.util.ArrayList<controllers.User>)'

Comment: I change the ArrayList name to Test and it didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that I imported the wrong java lib for the play Result .
the right one is :

```
import play.mvc.Result;
```